# In-place Upgrade of Windows Server 2008 to R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, upgrade

I would like to make an in-place upgrade from Windows Server 2008 to R2.

If you have done this:

a) Was it a boring no-brainer, or was it a fly by the seat of the pants journey of excitement?

b) When the upgrade was over did you find any stuff that did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the first thing to bear in mind is that Server 2008 R2 is 64 Bit only, so if your currently running the 32 Bit version of Server 2008 then an in-place upgrade is a no-go, you'll have to do a fresh install

You also cannot do cross SKU or cross languge upgrades.

With that in mind, an upgrade from 2008 x64 was a relatively painless experience for me. Admittedly this server was just a standard file and print sever, with nothing special on there, but it was a smooth experience, everything worked afterwards and had no problems since.

Comment: Since none of my 2003 or 2008 servers are running 64 bit code its all rebuilds for me. I think the 32bit to 64bit transition is key here for most that just assume they can apply this like they did prior service packs.

Comment: Yep, the 64bit transition has, and probably will be an issue for a while. The transition of Exchange to x64 caused alot of problems. Hopefully in a few years when everyone is on 64 Bit we can forget about it.

Comment: Luckily, I have a 64-bit version or W2K8, so your answer is music to my ears.

Comment: Well I did it.  Windows R2 Upgraded without any significant problem.